# setMinutes not gettng expected result

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have the following js codes:

```
// set a date time say 2 Oct
var localTime = new Date(2016, 9, 2, 4, 0, 0);

// set time to 23:59:59
localTime.setHours(23, 59, 59, 0);  

console.log(localTime);  // // Sun Oct 02 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0800 (MYT), which is expected

// now minus 600 minutes, which should be 10 hours
localTime.setMinutes(-600);
console.log(localTime);  // Sun Oct 02 2016 13:00:59 GMT+0800 (MYT)
```

When I minus 600 minutes from that time, I am expecting it to minus 10 hours which should be 13:59:59 but it's printing 13:00:59

What is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Date.prototype.setMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes) does not add/remove minutes from the time you have. It sets the minutes value for your date. The argument you provide is:

> **minutesValue**
>
> An integer between 0 and 59, representing the minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Dymos, this leads me to do it correctly like this localTime.setMinutes(localTime.getMinutes() - 600);